# Jquery check which element has been dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Is there a way to check which .draggable element has been dropped on a .droppable ?

I have a .droppable box and many elements which are .draggable.

I need to make that if an element has been dropped, it can still be dragged, but not dropped again.
.droppable triggers an event and if I drop the same object, it triggers it again and I dont want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to see which element has been dropped last and what elements have been dropped alltogether

```
var lastdropped;
var alreadydropped = new Array();


$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        lastdropped = $(event.srcElement).attr('class').split(' ')[0];

alreadydropped.push(lastdropped);
}
})
```